# How to behave when your nearby coworker looks at what you're doing?

Tags: behavior

I have some colleagues who often look at what I'm doing, especially when I turn around, left, or right to get or check something. Is this behavior acceptable or normal? It makes me uncomfortable.

What should I do next time to avoid his or her uninvited curiosity? Actually, I do not want to be stared at at such moments because I'm not looking at or talking to him or her on such occasions.

Comment: Do they look at you when you turn around ? Or, do they look at your computer/desk when you turn around ?

Comment: If they look at you when you turn around, could it be that your action of turning around makes some small noise which may cause some distraction to them (and they don't mean to be hostile to you because they are just checking to see if you are OK and everything is OK ?)

Comment: @Job_September_2020, I don't make any noise when turning around. They are just curious, seeing what I'm doing, or observing what I'm getting.

Comment: I still don't get what you are saying. Are they looking at you before you turn around, and do you only notice once you have turned around, or do they look up to see what you are doing in response to you turning around? Are they looking at you or are they looking at your work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the colleagues get intrigued by why he is getting up, or simply see movement in the corner of their eyes, its common for our mind to wonder when we are a little bored, I think its kind of unrealistic to expect your colleagues to not look at you when you move in a scenario where everyone is static.

I've had times when I'm just staring into oblivion, and it happens to be a colleague at the end of my stare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, this is normal behaviour, ignore it and focus on your work

Nothing in your question indicates they are going past what is considered the normal glance at something that draws attention, and movement in an otherwise stationary environment is naturally going to draw attention. As long as they're not persistently staring at you for minutes on end or deliberately doing something else at the same time to make you uncomfortable, I think you just need to let this go. If you work in an office with other people, you have to accept that someone will look at you from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply telling them "Feeling I'm being watched distracts me. I know you're trying to be helpful, but please give me a bit more space."?

The first and best solution to most interpersonal problems is to have the parties talk to each other and find an agreement that may not be optimal for either but that works well enough for both.

(Personally, I detest most open-plan offices partly because it's hard *not* to have a coworker in your field of vision not to not hear nearby conversations. I learned to deal with them, but I still think they cost companies more in lost productivity than they save.)

Comment: In a noisy team environment, you can put on a headphone with your favorite music, which will help you to focus on your work. That is a good way to block the noise.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do next time to avoid his or her uninvited curiosity?

1. Tell them "**How can I help you ?**" That will let them know that
   you notice their behavior. They will have to explain what they are
   doing to you.
2. Tell them "**Please don't do that again because it makes me feel**
   **uncomfortable** or **uneasy** **when someone looks at my workplace**."
3. If they still do that again, then you can tell them if they don't
   stop, you may need to take this to the team lead, supervisor, or
   manager.
4. If they ignore your warning and keep on doing this to you, then
   proceed to talk to  the team lead, supervisor, or manager.

---

**Talking to the manager is a major escalation. So, before talking to the manager, you can try these 2 things that hopefully will make them stop:**

**(A) Do they look at your computer ?**

If yes, then lock your computer screen when you turn around. This will send the signal to them that you don't want anyone to look at your computer.

---

**(B) Do they look at your book, documents, graph or drawing on your desk ?**

If yes, then put some big cover on top of your book, graph or drawing when you turn around. This will send a signal to them.

Comment: Because I felt uncomfortable, I did block the view by using a spare screen. However, some colleague just persistently looked at what I was getting, and sometimes had some comments on it. I think he's not hostile, but curious (he's an extrovert). Meanwhile, I'm kinda introvert, and dislike being watched like this.

Comment: @sanba06c is it one individual or two/three colleagues "checking up” or just being bored and not having enough work to be engaged with? How often in the day do they disturb you? Is it every day or only once in a while, enough to be annoying or intimidating? Please answer in the question, the more details you can provide the easier is it for users to understand your situation.

Comment: @sanba06c That seems like a "you" problem you need to solve. There's nothing wrong with being a little bored and looking for a distraction (aka you) or just wanting to chat. You'd be better to fix the underlying cause/trauma then to force others to stop glancing in your direction. What do you do when you are driving and everyone is looking at you ?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, The former colleague who sat near me never stared at me when I did some of my own stuff, but the new guy often does. Therefore, it triggered my uncomfort.

Comment: @sanba06c, Maybe, the reason the new guy stares at you is that he is actually **NEW** at the your company, and is so eager to observe and learn from the workers who have worked there for a long time. Maybe, he is trying to make new friends in his own way and he is not aware that his way makes you feel uncomfortable.